# calling tensorflow from keras.backend

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am learning Keras and Thensorflow for deep learning and I have a question.

With this imports:

```python
 import tensorflow as tf
 from keras import backend as K
```

Is there a difference between these two calls:

```python
K.foo
```

and

```python
tf.foo
```

?

In which conditions are they equivalent ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there may be a difference.

Keras is built **on top of** a backend. This backend may be Tensorflow, Theano or CNTK.

So, a function from keras will call a function from the backend, something like this:

```
#at keras.backend 
def foo(args**):

    #there may be some preprocessing or inversion in dimensions
    return tf.foo(args_that_may_be_different**)
```

It's impossible to have an answer for **all functions**. Some are indeed exactly the same, some may have a difference.

You can search the [backend codes](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/tree/master/keras/backend), speficially the [tensorflow backend](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py) and see how keras handles each function.